# Swift: Remove All from the Subview

Tags: swift, uiimageview, subview, superview

I create multiple objects under the same name and adding them into the Subview (variables are in german).

```
    wandX = (screenBreite - ((felderAnzX - 0) * feldBreite))
    wandY = ( screenHoehe - ((felderAnzY - 5) * feldBreite))

    for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        wand1 = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(wandX, wandY, feldBreite, feldBreite))
        wand1.image = wand
        self.addSubview(wand1)
        wandXarray.insert(wandX, atIndex: i)
        wandYarray.insert(wandY, atIndex: i)
        wandX = wandX + feldBreite
    }
```

(Creating a row of walls)

But if I want to remove them with `wand1.removeFromSuperview()` it only removes the last object it added. A possible solution I found is putting another object on top and delete all references. With many object and many stages the problem is the CPU usage.

Edit: Using the method `self.view.subviews.removeAll()`is getting me following error:

> Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'subviews' is a get-only property

Comment: `self.add.Subview(wand1)`. How this line can run?

Comment: Thank you. I made a mistake while copying the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wand1 = UIImageView(... is rewriting your reference over and over, so you will never be able to remove anything but the last item created from the superview.  You are either going to have to use an array or dictionary:

```
class Class
{
    var array = [UIImageView]();
    ...
    func something()
    {
    ...
    for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    let wand1 = UIImageView();
    wand1.image = wand
    array.append(UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(wandX, wandY, feldBreite, feldBreite)))
    self.add.Subview(wand1)//Dunno how this works but it is your code
    wandXarray.insert(wandX, atIndex: i)
    wandYarray.insert(wandY, atIndex: i)
    wandX = wandX + feldBreite
   }
   ...
   func removeThisImage(index : Int)
   {
       array[index].removeFromSuperView();
   }
```

Or you can create object references for every image you create, each with a unique name

//NO LONGER ALLOWED
If you just want to remove all subviews from a view and not concerned about removing specifics,  just call `self.subviews.removeAll()` where self is the view that contains your subviews.
//

Looks like you will have to write your own extension method to handle this:

```
extension UIView
{
    func clearSubviews()
    {
        for subview in self.subviews as! [UIView] {
            subview.removeFromSuperview();
        }
    }
}
```

Then to use it, it is just `self.view.clearSubviews();`

Comment: Both are good tips. For my problem the second one `self.subviews.removeAll()` fits perfectly. I do have a problem though if I use it.  "Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'subviews'" is the error message.

Comment: if you are inside the view controller, then it is self.view.subviews

Comment: Than I got a different error still in the same line. "Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'subview' is a get-only property"

Comment: Looks like apple wants you have the children remove themselves from the parents,  I do not remember it always being like that, but I haven't used it like that in years,  I guess you will have to use the first method, but do it in a for loop,  I have modified my answer